# How to install PIM Community Edition

Tags: akeneo

### (This is the guide modified, it worked for me)
How to install Akeneo PIM for testing/dev inUbuntu 20.04 LTS (my way)

Change localhost name (optional):

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
    (add this or modify)
    127.0.0.1   localhost
    127.0.0.1   akeneo-pim.local
```

Install apache2 and modules:

```
sudo apt install apache2 curl aspell php-apcu-bc php-pear php-apcu php7.4-fpm php7.4 libapache2-mod-php7.4 php7.4-cli php7.4-common php7.4-xml php7.4-mysql php7.4-gd php-imagick php7.4-tidy php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-curl php7.4-mbstring php7.4-zip php7.4-soap php7.4-bcmath php7.4-intl php7.4-xsl php7.4-json zip unzip --install-recommends
```

(modify both php.ini)

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
    memory_limit = 2G
    date.timezone = America/New_York
    apc.enable_cli = 1

a2enmod rewrite proxy_fcgi

sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf    
    user = www-data
    group = www-data
    listen = /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
    listen.owner = www-data
    listen.group = www-data
    ## Optional: this can help to optimize if you have little memory in your virtual machine.
    # pm = ondemand
    # pm.max_children = 80
    # pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
    # pm.max_requests = 200
   
sudo service apache2 restart    
sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```

Add the Akeneo site to web server:

```
sudo mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.bak
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName akeneo-pim.local

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
        
        <Directory /var/www/html/public>
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted

            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/public/bundles>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </Directory>

        <FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
        </FilesMatch>

        SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/akeneo-pim_error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/akeneo-pim_access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

Test if everything is working in the config (you might get some warning that will solve later)

```
   sudo apache2ctl configtest
   sudo service apache2 restart
```

Install Mysql, create db/user:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client --install-recommends
    (Install phpmyadmin if you like):
    sudo apt install phpmyadmin --install-recommends
```

Create DB and user:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
    CREATE DATABASE akeneo_pim;
    CREATE USER akeneo_pim@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'akeneo-pim';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON akeneo_pim.* TO akeneo_pim@localhost;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    EXIT

Configure root with password (optional):
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    EXIT;
    
Add other users as root (optional):   
    CREATE USER 'youruser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'CFKLDLNA'; 
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO youruser@localhost;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    EXIT;
```

Install JDK and ElasticSearch:

```
sudo apt install -y openjdk-11-jdk --install-recommends

wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
sudo echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elasticsearch
```

Options to limit memory usage (test as you need)

```
    sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options.d/jvm.options
    -Xms2g
    -Xmx2g

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

If Elasticsearch wont start at boot, give it little more timeout wait:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d
    echo -e "[Service]\nTimeoutStartSec=250" | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d/startup-timeout.conf
    sudo systemctl show elasticsearch | grep ^Timeout
```

Options for Akeneo:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/elasticsearch.conf
    vm.max_map_count=262144
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Install NODE12:

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt install -y nodejs
```

Install YARN:

```
cd ~
wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg 
sudo apt-key add pubkey.gpg 
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
    deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main
sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
```

Install Composer:

```
cd ~
    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
    php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '906a84df04cea2aa72f40b5f787e49f22d4c2f19492ac310e8cba5b96ac8b64115ac402c8cd292b8a03482574915d1a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
    php composer-setup.php
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
    sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Install Akeneo-PIM:

```
sudo rm /var/www/html/*
```

(Must be an empty folder)

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html
php -d memory_limit=4G /usr/local/bin/composer create-project --prefer-dist akeneo/pim-community-standard . "5.0.*@stable"
```

(accept allow-plugins)

Config .env as you need to match what you enter before:

```
nano /var/www/html/.env.local 
    APP_ENV=prod
    APP_DATABASE_HOST=localhost
    APP_DATABASE_PORT=null
    APP_DATABASE_NAME=akeneo_pim
    APP_DATABASE_USER=akeneo_pim
    APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=akeneo_pim
    APP_INDEX_HOSTS='localhost:9200'
```

Start installation in production mode:
(install this if you need: sudo apt make gcc)

```
cd /var/www/html    
NO_DOCKER=true make prod 
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
sudo chmod ug+rw /var/www/html/var/cache /var/www/html/var/logs /var/www/html/public
```

Create an admin user:

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo -u www-data php bin/console pim:user:create
User/Pass: youruser/CFKLDLNA
```

Cron job for Akeneo:

```
sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/console akeneo:batch:job-queue-consumer-daemon --env=prod -vvv >>/var/www/html/var/logs/daemon_logs.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem.

The [official](https://docs.akeneo.com/latest/install_pim/manual/system_requirements/system_install_ubuntu_2004.html#id1) manual install guide tells you to create a new virtualhost on port *:80 called /etc/apache2/sites-available/**akeneo-pim.local.conf**

And then enable it with a2ensite.  If you do so, you will also have 000-default.conf enabled as it comes defaulted enabled with apache.

So, you have to replace the 000-default.conf contents with [whats is in the guide here](https://docs.akeneo.com/latest/install_pim/manual/system_requirements/system_install_ubuntu_2004.html#creating-the-virtual-host-file)

Then restart apache and it works, but in port 80 (not in por 8080 as told in the guide, think that is just for docker)

Also you need to create a new user/pass as the admin/admin is just for docker install, you can create user with this command ran in your document-root akeneo folder. You have to run it with the same user that runs apache and the document-root akeneo directory permissions (if not it will give cant write/access errors)

In my case apache and php7.4-fpm runs with www-data as the permissions in /var/www/html/ (my documentroot where akeneo CE is installed)

So to add user:
cd /var/www/html
sudo -u www-data php bin/console pim:user:create

Hope it helps, will try to add the clean guide if it helps someone else, or just ask, will help if I can.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please add a clean guide? I'm also stuck at the installation part. When I do composer create-project I get error "mkdir(): Permission denied". I think that's because it will create the project at /srv/pim. In your initial post you said you create project in home? Would be really nice if you could do a clean step by step installation guide. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi @hardy123480, there I change the post, hope it helps you install it!

Answer (score 0):

That is an apache misconfiguration. If you do not use the docker-setup you will have no 8080 unless configured. The guide goes for the docker, if you do not use it you need to adapt the config yourself.

The `{pim-install}/public` folder is the main entry point where your apache config points to just `{pim-install}`. Adapt the host-configuration and you are fine. See this part: https://docs.akeneo.com/latest/install_pim/manual/system_requirements/system_install_ubuntu_2004.html#id1

Where the Document-Root points to `.../public`
The routing will handle the other calls (like for `bundles/...`).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I follow those steps and points me to create a new virtualhost in port 80 and then enable it, so following the steps I will have two sites enabled, I mean the 000-default.conf (default one) and the newly created.  Is it ok this way? or do I have to replace the 000-default.conf with the content of akeneo-pim.local.conf and leave this last one disabled? (I updated the first post showing my akeneo-pim.local.conf, just to be sure you can correct me) thanks.

Comment: If you have multiple Hosts configured at the same port make sure you are accessing it correctly which means in your case `http://akeneo-pim.local`. The virtual host responds to the configured name. Apache default tries to capture everything else. I suggest using only one active configuration if you are unsure. `akeneo-pim.local` you will have to point to your virtual box, or add the ip to the server name otherwise: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Thank you very much Plel, yes, I supposed that conflicted my apache config, I tried to follow the official guide step by step thinking it would work, but it needed some work and extra knowledge.